# 109 bit tree comparator with generate and for loop

Tags: for-loop, verilog, comparator

I am trying to write a Verilog code for the 109-bit tree comparator, but I am still new to the generate loop.

[image: Here is the block diagram for the 109-bit tree comparator.]

I have written some code so far, but I am getting some errors. Also, I am not sure if I can use 2-d arrays for g and l signals?

```
parameter NUM_OF_BITS = 109;
parameter NUM_OF_LEVELS = 7;
genvar i;

for (x=0; x<NUM_OF_LEVELS; x=x+1) begin:
    generate for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_BITS/((2*x)+1); i=i+1) begin: MCs
        mag_comp2_1 mc (in0[2*i+1:2*i],in1[2*i+1:2*i],g[x][i],l[x][i]);
    end
    endgenerate
    NUM_OF_BITS = NUM_OF_BITS/2;
end
```

Comment: i) Telling us what the errors are would help us. ii) The format of the `generate` statement changed between IEEE 1364-2001 and IEEE 1364-2005. You seem to have a strange mixed syntax between the two. How about putting the `generate` and `endgenerate` on the outside?

Comment: iii) `x` needs to be a `genvar`, too. iv) I expect you need to calculate `NUM_OF_BITS` _statically_, in other words I expect you'll have to remove the line `NUM_OF_BITS = NUM_OF_BITS/2;` and instead calculate the inner loop limit inside the `for` statement.

Comment: are you using `system verilog`? in this case, the first for loop is already a generate block. `generate` keyword inside of a generate block could be an issue. remove it. If you are using a regular verilog, still remove the `generate` from where it is and put it around the whole loop structure. You can do it in system verilog as well, if you wish.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I dont understand the need of generate for the outer for loop. The outer for loop is just for the levels, And the generate block as I know it is used to generate instances for a module that I am using for 2:1 magnitude comparator. Could any one of you please explain more?

Comment: @Serge I am using verilog and not system verilog. Can you explain you do i need a generate keywork for the outer for loop. Can't I have a generate for loop inside another loop?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Please comment on `mag_comp2_1 mc (in0[2*i+1:2*i],in1[2*i+1:2*i],g[x][i],l[x][i])` as well as I am not certain if this would work or not?

Comment: i added correct syntax for generate/endgenerate in the answer.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I have updated the code, could you please verify it? Does it look right?

Comment: I am getting errors that `g is not a memory` & `l is not a memory`

Answer (score 1):

Why not define the interconnections in for blocks? This way it will be more convenent for you.

An incomplete example:

```
parameter NUM_OF_BITS = 220;
parameter NUM_OF_LEVELS = 7;
genvar i,x;

generate for (x=1; x<NUM_OF_LEVELS; x=x+1) 
begin: Ls
    wire [NUM_OF_BITS/(2**x)-1:0] output1;
    wire [NUM_OF_BITS/(2**x)-1:0] output2;
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_BITS/(2**x); i=i+1) 
    begin: MCs
        if (x == 1) 
        begin
            // for the first level connect inputs to the module
            mag_comp2_1 mc (input1[2*i+1:2*i],input2[2*i+1:2*i],output1[i],output2[i]);
        end
        else 
        begin
            // for other levels connect ouputs of the previous level
            mag_comp2_1 mc (Ls[x-1].output1[2*i+1:2*i],Ls[x-1].output2]2[2*i+1:2*i],output1[i],output2[i]);
        end              
    end
end
endgenerate
```

Comment: Thanks, Alper I made a new version for the code without any condition to check (which I believe would be more efficient, pls tell if I am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

you need something like the following. `generate` .. `endgenerate` tell the compiler to unroll all the loops and conditional statements between the keywords. So, you end up with a lot of instances of the module **mag_comp2_1**

```
parameter NUM_OF_BITS = 109;
parameter NUM_OF_LEVELS = 7;
genvar i, x;

generate
  for (x=0; x<NUM_OF_LEVELS; x=x+1) begin: externloop
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_BITS/((2*x)+1); i=i+1) begin: MCs
        mag_comp2_1 mc (in0[2*i+1:2*i],in1[2*i+1:2*i],g[x][i],l[x][i]);
    end
   //NUM_OF_BITS = NUM_OF_BITS/2;
  end
endgenerate
```

Comment: I updated the code could you please verify if its correct?

Comment: I am getting errors that `g is not a memory` & `l is not a memory`

Comment: @AshutoshJain I have rolled back your edits to return the code to that in  the original question. The idea of Stack Overflow is that questions become a useful resource for future googlers. By changing your question so much, the answers and comments make no sense. Your error regarding `l` and `g` not being memories is a completely different issue. Please ask another question and I or someone else will be glad to answer it.

Comment: @AshutoshJain anyway, both `g` and `l` must be declared. You used them  as two dimensional arrays in your case. No definition had been provided in your example.  So it is difficult to comment on them without reinventing the whole algorithm for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
parameter NUM_OF_BITS = 220;
parameter NUM_OF_LEVELS = 7;
genvar x,i;

wire [NUM_OF_LEVELS:0][NUM_OF_BITS:0] g, l;

assign g[0] = in0;
assign l[0] = in1;

generate for (x=1; x<NUM_OF_LEVELS; x=x+1) begin: Ls
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_BITS/(2**x); i=i+1) begin: MCs
        mag_comp2_1 mc (g[x-1][2*i+1:2*i],l[x-1][2*i+1:2*i],g[x][i],l[x][i]);
    end
end
endgenerate

assign gt = g[NUM_OF_LEVELS][0];
assign lt = l[NUM_OF_LEVELS][0];
```

Comment: @MatthewTaylor please verify this version of the code.

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler please verify this version of the code.